# Why the return JSON will contains lots of special characters and how to process it

Tags: apex, controller, json

As you can see the return JSON from a salesforce  controller contains lots of escaped characters

`&#39;`
`&quot;`

```
{
  &quot;status&quot; : &quot;SUCCESS&quot;,
  &quot;Name&quot; : &quot;Liz D&#39;Cruz&quot;,
}
```

What's the normal way to handle this problem?
I think to deal this problem case by case is not a smart way.

eg: STRING.replace(xxx, yyy)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to be more specific about the context involved here. You should be able to provide exact reproduction steps here. Are you doing some Visualforce remoting by chance?

Comment: Hi newBike. I linked a possible answer to your question that I found, but I didn't use the Duplicate Question feature because I wanted to give you a chance to respond, and your question would have been automatically closed. Please let us know if that gives you the information you were looking for.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think you gave me the fix. should I close this thread myself?

Comment: @newBike I can close it so that future visitors will also have a direct link to the answer. Glad I could help!